# Is '#IF DEBUG' deprecated in modern programming?

Tags: c#

This is my first StackOverflow question so be nice! :-)

I recently came across the following example in some C# source code:

```
public IFoo GetFooInstance()
{
    #IF DEBUG
        return new TestFoo();
    #ELSE
        return new Foo();
    #ENDIF
}
```

Which lead me to these questions:

1. Is the use of "#IF DEBUG" unofficially deprecated? If not what is considered to be a good implementation of its use?
2. Using a class factory and/or tools like MOQ, RhinoMocks, etc how could the above example be implemented?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using an IoC container, the entire function becomes redundant, instead of calling GetFooInstance you'd have code similar to:

```
ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IFoo>();
```

The setup of your IoC container could be in code or through a configuration file.

Comment: This answer combined with Mitch Wheat's answer/reasoning looks to be the best answer to the problem. Thanks guys.

Comment: This doesn't answer the initial question which was is it still used and where/when etc. :(

Answer (score 4):

Nope. We use it all the time to sprinkle diagnostic information in our assemblies. For example I have the following shortcut used when debugging:

```
#if DEBUG
        if( ??? ) System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
#endif
```

Where I can change ??? to any relevant expresion like Name == "Popcorn". etc. This ensures that none of the debugging code leaks into the release build.

Comment: What would be the advantage of this over a conditional breakpoint?

Comment: The ability to turn debug settings on or off by changing a variable.

Comment: I used to do that but lately I've started using Debug.Assert() - it does a very similar job but without the occasional headache caused by the debug executable having a slightly different code execution path than the release executable.

Comment: The advantage to this over conditional breakpoints is speed. Often I'll place this code inside a loop. With a conditional breakpoint the debugger has to break into the application, pausing each of the threads, evaluate the condition, then resume execution. Withthe #if DEBUG method it evaluates the conditions in "real time".

Comment: Thanks Paul your answer shows that it still has its uses in certain situations.

Answer (score 1):

Just like some of the other posters have mentioned, I use #if statements all the time for debugging scenarios.

The style of code that you have posted is more of a factory creation pattern, which is common.  I use it frequently, and not only do I not consider it depreciated, I consider the use of #if and #define statements to be an important tool in my bag of tricks.

I believe CastleWindsor (http://www.castleproject.org/container/index.html) also has an IoC container.  I believe the general pattern is that in the configuration file, you state that TestFoo or IFoo will be the class created when CastleWindsor initializes the IoC container.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I would strongly advise AGAINST using "`#IF DEBUG`" except in rare circumstances

It was common place in C, but you should not use in a modern language such as C# for several reasons:

1. Code (and header) files become nightmarish
2. It is too easy to make a mistake and leave in/out a conditional for a Release build
3. Testing becomes a nightmare: need to test many combinations of builds
4. Not all code is compile checked, unless you compile for ALL possible
   conditional symbols!

@Richard's answer shows how you can replace using IoC (much cleaner).

Answer (score -1):

I strongly deprecate #if; instead use `if` with a manifest constant:

```
#define DEBUG 0   // actually in a header or on a command line

public IFoo GetFooInstance()
{
    if (DEBUG)
        return new TestFoo();
    else
        return new Foo();
}
```

Why is `#IF` bad?  Because in the `#IF` version, **not all code is typechecked**.  For complicated, long-lived codes, bitrot can set in, and then suddenly you need `DEBUG` but the code won't build.  With the `if` version, the code always builds, and given even the most minimal optimization settings, your compiler will completely eliminate the unreachable code.  In other words, as long as `DEBUG` is *known* to be always 0 (and `#define` will do that for you), there is *no run-time cost* to using `if`.

And you are guaranteed that if you change `DEBUG` from 0 to 1, the system will build.

Comment: However, using that code moves the IF conditional to runtime rather than compile time, which may result in slower execution. Of course that's a simple example but sometimes they get complex...

Comment: @Billy: The key is to guarantee that the condition is a compile-time constant---that way ensures there is no run-time cost, and execution time is exactly the same both ways.

Comment: Assuming that optimization is made, and relying on the C# compiler to do this sort of thing is sketchy at best. It doesn't like to do anything but very simple optimizations -- for example, 1 + x + 5 will not get constant folded into 6 + x. Combine that with the JIT's poor inlining engine (ignoring 3.5 SP1) and you can inadvertently have some surprising results.

Comment: Also... `not all code is typechecked` ... for a constant does it really matter of not?

Comment: @Billy: It's the fact that the 'if' branch is not typechecked that is a potential problem.  If your debug code is complicated, and there is nothing forcing you to update it when the APIs change... then suddenly when you want your debug code, it may not build.

Comment: @Promit: I wouldn't expect the C# front end to do this optimization; I'd expect it to be done by the MSIL (.NET) compiler.  But I don't know much about the internals; it could be just as bad as you say...

Answer (score -2):

Your compiler should be smart enough to figure out that:

```
final DEBUG=false;
...
if(DEBUG)
    return new debugMeh();
else
    return new meh();
```

the method never has to be called and can, in fact, be compiled out of the final assembly.

That plus the fact that even the unoptimized performance difference wouldn't amount to anything significant makes using some different syntax mostly unnecessary.

EDIT:  I'd like to point out something interesting here.  Someone in comments just said that this:

```
#IF DEBUG
    return new TestFoo();
#ELSE
    return new Foo();
#ENDIF
```

was easier to write than this:

```
if(DEBUG)
    return new TestFoo();
else
    return new Foo();
```

I find it really amazing the lengths that people will go to to defend the way they've done things as correct.  Another said that they would have to define a DEBUG variable in each file.  I'm not sure about C#, but in Java we generally put a

```
public static final DEBUG=true;
```

in our logger or another central factory object (although we actually find better ways to do this--such as using DI).

I'm not saying the same facilities don't exist in C#, I'm just amazed at the lengths people will go to to prove the solution they hold onto because of habit is correct.

Comment: A simple #if is easier to write and it communicates your intention better that the code above

Comment: I agre Robert. Also, the regular if statement will be evaluated in release code (and determined to be false). That may be a concern for some people.

Comment: Also you can set the DEBUG symbol globally. The variable would have to be defined in every class separately...

Comment: @Joey no, a good compiler will optimize the entire if out if the DEBUG variable evaluates to a constant false, that was kind of my point.  There is no difference except that #if uses a different syntax.  Do you think maybe we should have a different style if for each possibility so it "stands out"?  Maybe @if for testing booleans, and &if for testing for nulls?  Or how about we just use a single syntax to solve a single problem?